# Looking for USB to USB serial cable

Tags: serial, pi-zero-w

I having a `raspberry pi zero w` and a normal laptop as host. Instead of using `UART`, I want to know is it possible to connect to the USB port in `raspberry pi zero w` as a serial device via USB to USB cable, with a serial module I guess. If there has such cable. On the host side, I need to install VCP driver https://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/VCP.htm. So I think I need to install a similar driver on the raspberry pi for recognizing the USB device as a serial device.

**Update:**

After Googleing, I got a part of the solution, which means I didn't confirm it works or not.

First, the cable is [USB Null Modem Cable.](https://www.ftdichip.com/Products/Cables/USBtoUSB.htm)
[image]

And Linux kernel already has the VCP driver inside. But I want to try bare metal programming on raspberry pi, so I need to port the VCP driver to it.

Comment: @jsotola if yes  could you please give the details, to prove it is the workable solution.

Comment: Please make an answer for the solution you have found and accept it after two days. Only accepting an answer will finish the question and it will not endless pop up again for years. For the question to port the VCP driver you should ask a new question but I'm not sure it it belongs to Raspberry Pi.